# Highcharts show/hide datalabel of selected point

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Still have a big trouble on working with highcharts datalabels. Now I need to show and hide datalabels by clicking on the points. Tried this:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect : true,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        select /*click*/: function () {
                            this.options.dataLabels.enabled = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                            this.update();
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
```

But get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'enabled' of undefined`.

There're point events at PlotOptions level as `point.select` and `point.click` but from examples given at highcharts.com I can't get any help.

Also I can't figure out should I work with point or maybe with the certain serie through the array access `like series[0].data[1]` etc.?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the updated property into the `Point.update()` [method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update).

```
          point:{
                events:{
                    click: function(){
                        // determine toggle state
                        // on first click this.dataLabels is undefined...
                        var e = !this.dataLabels || this.dataLabels.enabled ? false : true;
                        this.update({
                            dataLabels:{
                                enabled: e
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/7wLxwfq6/) which toggles them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how can I make it invisible by default? If I set dataLabels : {enabled : false} it doesn't show them even by clicking on a point((

Comment: Change condition to: `!this.dataLabels || !this.dataLabels.enabled ? true : false;`

Comment: @Steve.B, updated fiddle with logic reversed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7wLxwfq6/3/)