# Highcharts. Is it possible to show data labels programmatically

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592557/highcharts-show-hide-datalabel-of-selected-point) my question I can show/hide datalabels by clicking on a point. But at this example `dataLabels enabled` show be set to `true` by default, otherwise I can't show them. Nothing happens when I click on a point.

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: function() {               
            // on first click this.dataLabels is undefined...
            var e = !this.dataLabels || this.dataLabels.enabled ? false : true;
                this.update({
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: e
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works fine only if I set

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change condition to:

```
                    click: function(){
                        var e = !this.dataLabels || !this.dataLabels.enabled ? true : false;
                        this.update({
                            dataLabels:{
                                enabled: e
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7wLxwfq6/2/

Comment: Why does it work at jsfiddle but doesn't in my page I've created?! I just copy and paste your code in my page...

Comment: Fixed it... Downloaded the latest highcharts version.